# Add new folder to portal

Tags: dotnetnuke

My code to add a new folder to the main website always worked, but when i try to add a new folder in a portal it can't add the folder. It simply returns null back to me.

I quess the problems lies in the folderpath, in my main website i just could use the new foldername for the folderpath.

I tried the following locations for the folderpath without any success:

1. Foldername
2. G:\inetpub\wwwroot\newdnn\Portals\2
3. G:\inetpub\wwwroot\newdnn\Portals\2\foldername
4. Portals\2
5. Portals\2\foldername

The code i am using:

```
 // Get folder mapping
 var folderMapping = FolderMappingController.Instance.GetFolderMapping(PortalId, "Secure");

 // Add folder and get the result back of the folder information
                var folder = FolderManager.Instance.AddFolder(new FolderMappingInfo
                {
                    FolderProviderType = folderMapping.FolderProviderType,
                    FolderMappingID = 9,
                    Priority = 2,
                    PortalID = PortalId,
                }, "filePath");
```

The folder is null after i added it, it should contain the details of the folder.

Any help is appreciated a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found the problem.

I forgot that the mappingproviderId is different for each portal, so i had to do a query to the database and get the right mappingproviderId. When i did that it worked fine for me.

Would have been nice if dnn throwed an erron..